# Send rtf to printer vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have this code and I have a little problem. Printing start, but result is only empty papper.

```
Dim printme As New Printing.PrintDocument
printme.DocumentName = "c:\testprint.rtf"
printme.Print()
```

Does any have other idea, how I can send testprinter.rtf to printer?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.documentname.aspx) for the `PrintDocument.DocumentName` property:

> The DocumentName property does not specify the file to print. Rather, you specify the output to print by handling the [PrintPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage.aspx) event. For an example, see the [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) class overview.

That explains why your code isn't working, because setting the `DocumentName` property doesn't actually cause that document to be printed. You get an empty sheet of paper coming out because you haven't written code to tell the printer to print anything.

So use this code instead:

```
Dim printme As New Printing.PrintDocument
AddHandler printme.PrintPage, AddressOf printme_PrintPage
printme.Print()
```

And then add a `printme_PrintPage` event handler method, in which you write code to print the file.